# Is there any way to open multiple hyperlinks at once in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I a have created list of email hyperlinks in my spreadsheet using only hyperlink formula (not VBA) with email content based on value of a few defined cells.

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&F16 &"?cc="&G16 &"&subject="&email_template!$B$4 &"&body="&H16 &"%0d%0a%0d%0a"&email_template!$B$5 &"%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a"&email_template!$B$6&"%0d%0a%0d%0a"&email_template!$B$7&"%0d%0a" &email_template!$B$8 &"%0d%0a"&email_template!$B$9 &"%0d%0a"&email_template!$B$10;"Open Email Template")
```

It works fine when I click one by one on each hyperlink cell that I want to open. It opens new email windows (Outlook in my case) with all predefined data exactly how I want.

However I am wondering if there is any way to open multiple email hyperlinks by clicking one button?
I tried it using this VBA code. It works, but only for web hyperlinks or email hyperlink without any body, cc etc. customatization.

```
Sub DD_OpenEmail()

Dim HL As Hyperlink
For Each HL In Selection.Hyperlinks
HL.Follow
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Based on my limited research it sounds like everything after the `?` is ignored. I think you would move those to one of the parameter that `follow` or alternately `followhyperlink` uses. That would require you parsing your formula (or reconstructing your data table) within your VBA. Good luck.